# Rotate UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to rotate a disclosure button? I'd like it to point down if a row is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubtful. The iPhone images are designed with a 3D appearance with shadows, etc. that would look wrong if rotated.

Answer (score 0):

By assigning an appropriate transformation you can rotate the button by 90 degrees:

```
  myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

However, I don't think that this is in compliance with Apple's design guidelines.